# Java 8: Stream optimization, invoke same method on the same instance twice

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, java-stream, monads

Does a stream have a cache or does it optimize same calls?

```
    list.stream()
            .filter(bean ->  manager.find(bean.getID()).getApi() != null)
            .peek(bean -> {
                Entity entity = manager.find(bean.getID());
                //... logic with entity here
                }
            });
```

How many times will `manager.find()` be called during iteration? Could you propose better way to implement this piece of code?

Comment: No, stream doesn't have any money. Did you mean "cache"?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. First, it doesn't compile, because you have an extra `}`. Second, there is no terminal operation, so nothing is streamed. If your code is a snippet, and there's more coming after, we don't know if you need `bean` later on, but if you don't, you could use `.map(bean ->  manager.find(bean.getID()))`.

Comment: Why do this? If you want a `Stream<Bean>` make one! That's what the `map` method is for... Also, your use of `peek` is horrid. `peek` is designed to inspect items in flight - not do business logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer

Change it for:

```
list.stream()
    .map(bean -> manager.find(bean.getID()))
    .filter(bean ->  bean.getApi() != null)
    .forEach(bean -> {
        //TODO
     });
```

The `map` will transform call manager.find in all elements, loading the in the memory with `manager.find(bean.getID())`

### Example of map:

`Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6).map(String::valueOf).forEach(System.out::println);`

1. `Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6)` -> We have a stream of Integer
2. `map(String::valueOf)` -> We will call `String.valueOf(i)` for all elements in the stream, transforming it to a stream of String.
3. `forEach(System.out::println);` will print all elements (Now Strings)

### Links

https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-map-examples/

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

http://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-stream-map-example

Comment: Worth noting that without a terminal operation, `peek` does absolutely nothing...

Comment: Yes..Changed for forEach. Thanks to notice that

Answer (score 6):

you might want to do it the other way around:

```
list.stream()
   .map(bean -> manager.find(bean.getID()))
   .filter(entity-> entity.getApi() != null)
   .forEach(entity -> { /* logic here*/ });
```